# PDF editor to comment and highlight academic papers with stylus support

Tags: windows, pdf, note-taking

I'm having some trouble finding a simple platform for commenting, highlighting, and drawing sketches over academic papers.

Some (soft) feature needs:

- Support for touch/stylus on Windows
- Some way of keeping track of PDFs and groups of papers

I've looked at One-Note, which is fantastic for taking direct notes! But not so much for editing pre-existing PDFs and exporting them without some issues. I've also looked at some chrome extensions for PDFs but they always seem to be pretty finicky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly suggest taking a look at [Evernote](https://evernote.com/) which is primarily aimed at the academic world, it features *depending on the selected plan*:

- Note taking *with stylus support & audio notes*
- PDF storage, organisation & searching
- PDF Markup
- Office Support
- Web Clipping
- Sharing within groups, etc.
- Collaboration
- Cross Platform Support including Mobile
- Web Interface & Applications
- *A lot more*

There 3 plans:

1. Basic *(Free)*
2. Premium *(Currently £4.99/month)*
3. Business *(Currently 10.99/user/month)*

But there are Free Trials, [Student Discounts](https://evernote.com/students) and I am reasonably sure that there **may** be some room for negotiation for Academic Institutions & Charities, etc.

***Note: I am only associated with Evernote as a user of their services & software.***

Answer (score 1):

Consider checking out [Drawboard PDF](https://www.drawboard.com/). It has tabs for multiple documents open at once, *excellent* stylus support for annotations, and a great set of other markup tools you'd want when marking up academic papers by hand (comments, text and freeform highlighting, several underline styles, etc.) I use it for active reading scientific papers myself, and it feels like I can do everything I would do if I had printed out the paper and marked it up by hand. And more!

There's a free trial, though the full version is also *well* worth the $10 USD I paid for it.